# Kotlin Coroutines with Spring request scoped beans

Tags: spring, kotlin

I have some code that is utilising request scoped beans in a function call from a coroutine. It seems like spring doesn't know that I am still inside the same request.

Is it possible to make spring understand I still want the request scoped bean even if the call is from a async Kotlin coroutine?

I get this error message when the code runs:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.wsContext': 
Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; 
consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
No thread-bound request found: 
Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? 
If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

Comment: I don't think that is yet possible. Co-routine support is being added in Spring 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

Coroutines are independent of the main thread, so you need to provide all data at the coroutines scope manually